# Partial differential operator is sum of order $0$ operators and composition of vector fields

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-bundles, vector-fields

Let $P:\Gamma(\Bbb R^n, E_0) \rightarrow \Gamma(\Bbb R^n, E_1)$ be a differential operator where $E_0$, $E_1$ are trivial vector bundles, with the standard bundle metric over $\Bbb R^n$.

In [page 28](https://ivv5hpp.uni-muenster.de/u/jeber_02/skripten/mainfile.pdf) of the notes, the author writes,

> We can write $P = \sum_{|\alpha| \le k } A^\alpha(x) D^\alpha $ with some smooth matrix-valued functions $A^\alpha$ and a composition of vector fields.

What does this mean explicitly? Why is this a composition of vector fields?

Comment: Are you asking how such an operator acts on sections of $\Gamma(\Bbb R^n, E_0)$, or why we can write a differential operator in such a way?

Comment: The author is just referring to the very definition you quoted in your previous post.

Comment: Sorry, question wasn't clear. I don't understand why it is a composition of vector fields.

Comment: To the best of my understanding, "composition of vector fields" is how the author thinks of $D^\alpha$. Indeed, if $|\alpha|=1$ then $D^\alpha$ is a vector field. In general, $D^\alpha$ is the composition of $|\alpha|$ vector fields.